# Where to place css files in Codeigneter

Tags: css, codeigniter

I am trying to just display view page with some style. My all other code is working correctly but the view page is not displaying the style.
I have placed the **`style.css`** file in the view folder of all view pages. Is it the right place to put the **`css`** file?

Answer (score 3):

**But First You must be set base_url Path of your project**

```
mysite/
     application/
             controllers/
             models/
             views/
             .
             .
      system/
      public/
            assets/
            css/
                style.css/     
            js/
            images/

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/assest/css/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is common pratice to create a folder named 'assets' or similar outside your application directory. This is for security reasons as you do not want to expose your application folder structure.

Reference to this folder using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this structure

```
mysite/
     application/
             controllers/
             models/
             views/
             .
             .
      system/
      public/
            css/
            js/
            images/
```

And you can include these files in your view like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/css/style.css" />
```

Here mysite is my site name. in which there are 3 folders. application which will contain all my code. system for core files and public for css, js and images. After that the above criteria should work.

Comment: I  tried this but still style is not linked to the view page..what is that base_url() function dose.

Comment: @HoaxerNilesh what is your structure please post it. You might be using it in a wrong way

Comment: application-controller,model,view,config,etc folders.                                                               system-                                                             model-                                                               public-css,js,images

Comment: You might want to mention that the `base_url()` function is part of the URL helper which will need to be enabled.

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file? You will have to add the public directory to your list of accessible directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in template then it is best practice to include all of your css files in your template header. it is best approach to use template, because it reduces your view code.
just include your css files after head tag

```
       <head> css files link </head>
```